# What is a public NXT api i can access?

Tags: api, nxt

Is there a public site where you can access the nxt api? like how blockchain.info does it. all i want to do is make queries to retrieve all the messages in the nxt network to see the activity.

Comment: I don't believe there is one by a reputable source and I would highly-discourage ever using a public node as a personal wallet.  If you do happen to find a public node, and you feel that you can trust the manager, be sure that they are using an encrypted connection.  If not, you will be sending your privkeys across in clear-text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your own node and access the page http://localhost:7876/test for a list of public APIs. You can also find some public peers which enable API access. Take a look at [peerexplorer.com](http://peerexplorer.com) for an up to date list.